# I'm looking for a word for when someone is making you feel obligated because of a favor they have done for you earlier

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

"Stop milking that favor" and "stop making me feel obligated" are two expressions I've heard so far. Though I'm not sure about their correctness. I was wondering if you could suggest an alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a useful word that avoids confrontation, but is still assertive, given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quits):

> **quits**
> On even terms, especially because a debt or score has been settled.

It can be applied to favours too. Here are some ways to say it:

> I think we're just about **quits** now, don't you?
>
> Let's call it **quits**.

The second suggestion is better said just after a favour has been returned or repaid.